# Email verification using secrettoken in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to verify the user by taking the secrettoken from the link sent in the email. I am able to extract the secrettoken but not able to update the value of active as true. 
Below is my code

```
router.route('/verify')
  .get((req,res)=>{

    console.log('request recieved');
    const token = req.query.id;

   User.updateOne(
  { secretToken: token },
  {
    $set: { price: true }

  },function(err,res){

    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    else{
      console.log('one document updated');
    }
  }
);

  });




"email": "surendrap720@gmail.com",
    "username": "surendrap720",
    "password": "$2a$10$UEKSpPpVWfZ3urclkayW6OcAUvscBrql23WU6fvfbI0Nd1jzo2Bxa",
    "type": "tutor",
    "secretToken": "5A6fXVh5gEObwUQxgpG4DpJ85COMJveJ",
    "active": false,
```

Comment: Hi, please provide the specific error message you are getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying `active` at all in your `updateOne` code.

change this:

```
$set: { price: true }
```

to this:

```
{ active: true }
```